# react-native making status bar animated

Tags: react-native

Initially, I have a black background with `light-content` barStyle but as I scroll up, the background color changes to white and I want to change the statusBar barStyle to 'dark-content'.

This is why I am trying to make my statusBar animated.

So far I have tried like this:

1. I made statusBar animated component

   `const AnimatedStatusBar = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(StatusBar)`
2. set Animated input/output range

   `scroll = new Animated.Value(0)`

   `statusBarColor = this.scroll.interpolate({
           inputRange: [0, SCROLL_HEIGHT],
           outputRange: ['white', 'black'],
           extrapolate: "clamp"
       })`
3. conditionally change barstyle.

   `<AnimatedStatusBar backgroundColor='white' barStyle={this.statusBarColor ==='white'? 'light-content':'dark-content'}  />`

However, this is not working. How could I make the statusBar animated so that I could change the `barStyle` when I scroll to the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

### iOS

1. I changed `<StatusBar/>` props `translucent` to `true`
2. `animated` prop in `<StatusBar/>` to true
3. get status bar height from top value of `useSafeArea` hook
4. Create simple  `Animated.View` having `100% width` and status bar `height`

### Android

1. Create `AnimatedStatusBar` with `Animated.createAnimatedComponent(StatusBar);`

Other steps are same

```
import { useSafeArea } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const AnimatedStatusBar = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(StatusBar);
function Page() {
  const { top: safeAreaTop } = useSafeArea();
  const barColorAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const barColor = barColorAnim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ['black', 'white'],
  });
  const [barStyle, setBarStyle] = useState('light-content');

  const toggle = () => {
    setBarStyle((style) =>
      style === 'light-content' ? 'dark-content' : 'light-content',
    );
    Animated.timing(barColorAnim, {
      useNativeDriver: false,
      duration: 300,
      toValue: barStyle === 'light-content' ? 1 : 0,
    }).start();
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: safeAreaTop,
          backgroundColor: barColor,
        }}
      />
      <AnimatedStatusBar
        animated={true}
        backgroundColor={barColor}
        barStyle={barStyle}
        translucent={true}
      />
      <Button title="Toggle" onPress={toggle} />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! can you show me how to do it without hooks?

Comment: It is not very different with class component.
You can understand `useState` as `this.state` and `this.setState`

And, about `useSafeArea`, you refer this [repo](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context)
Wrap your component with `<SafeAreaProvider></SafeAreaProvider` and set context of your component to `SafeAreaContext` and you can get safeArea top height

And `useRef`, This is just set `Animated.Value` to class field in constructor

Also, I strongly suggest you learn functional component and hooks! It is amazing

Comment: Why you are doing differently for the Android?

Comment: @HenriqueBruno It seems to animated={true} not working in Android

Comment: JFYI I have no issues with it on Android

Answer (score 0):

```
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Animated, StatusBar, Text } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const AnimatedStatusBar = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(StatusBar);
const barColorAnim = new Animated.Value(0);
const barColor = barColorAnim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ['black', 'white'],
});

export class App extends React.Component {
this.state = {
    barStyle: 'light-content'
};

render() {
    const toggle = () => {
        this.setState({
            barStyle: this.state.barStyle === 'light-content' ? 'dark-content' : 'light-content'
        })
        Animated.timing(barColorAnim, {
            useNativeDriver: false,
            duration: 300,
            toValue: this.state.barStyle === 'light-content' ? 1 : 0,
        }).start();
    };

    return (
        <>
            <SafeAreaProvider>
                <AnimatedStatusBar
                    animated={true}
                    backgroundColor={barColor}
                    barStyle={this.state.barStyle}
                    translucent={true}
                />

                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={toggle}><Text>Click toggle</Text></TouchableOpacity>
            </SafeAreaProvider>
        </>
    );
}
}
```